# Convert data types in d3.js without prior knowledge of property names (detect if a string contains only digits)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In d3.js. I can read in a user-uploaded CSV file in my web app like this:

```
d3.csv("upload.csv", function(data) {
  console.log(data[0]);
});
```

This results in everything being read in as a string. However, I need to be able to treat numeric data types as numbers.

If I knew the property names ahead of time, I could do something like this:

```
d3.csv("upload.csv", function(data) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.population = +d.population;
    d["land area"] = +d["land area"];
  });
  console.log(data[0]);
});
```

However, as this is user-provided data, there's no way to know the property names ahead of time. Is there a way to detect that the fields only contain numbers, then change the data type accordingly? Perhaps some sort of conditional statement with a regex test or something?

The examples were adapted from [this](http://learnjsdata.com/read_data.html) tutorial.

Comment: As you know by now, `d3.csv` will return the object values as strings. That being said, how it would be possible to *"to detect that the fields only contain numbers"*, if all the values are strings?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I am not very familiar with d3 at all, but I was thinking there could be an if / else statement that uses some sort of regex to test if only numbers are in the strings. I'm mostly an R programmer. I think I could show how I would do it in R if that would help.

Comment: Yes, that's possible. So, it could rephrase to *"detect if a string contain only digits"*, don't you agree?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Yes, good idea

Comment: I edited my answer to deal with negative numbers, scientific notation and floats as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**New Answer**:

D3 v5.8 introduced the very handy method [`d3.autotype`](https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv#autoType), which makes this task quite easy:

```js
var data = d3.csvParse(d3.select("#csv").text(), d3.autoType);

console.log(data);
```

```css
pre {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<pre id="csv">header1,header2,header3
foo,foo2,1212
bar,bar2,2345
baz,baz2,7623</pre>
```

---

(**Original Answer**)

As discussed in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43234286/convert-data-types-in-d3-js-without-prior-knowledge-of-property-names-detect-if#comment73538905_43234286), you can use a regex to check if the string contains only digits. Then, if it does, you coerce it to a number.

In the following demo I'm using a `<pre>` to store the data, since I cannot use the actual `d3.csv` function in the Stack snippet.

In the simulated CSV there are three columns. One of them, `header3`, has numbers. We know that, but the code doesn't: it just check all values using the regex and coerce the strings containing only digits to numbers.

```js
var data = d3.csvParse(d3.select("#csv").text());

data.forEach(function(d) {
  for (var key in d) {
    if (/^\d+$/.test(d[key])) {
      d[key] = +d[key]
    }
  }
});

console.log(data);
```

```css
pre {
  display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<pre id="csv">header1,header2,header3
foo,foo2,1212
bar,bar2,2345
baz,baz2,7623</pre>
```

This addresses your question, which is *"detect if a string contains only digits"*. However, if you want to deal with negative numbers, scientific notation and floats as well, you can drop the regex and use something way more elegant:

In JavaScript, `NaN` is not equal to anything, not even to itself. Since using the unary operator with something that is not a number returns `NaN`, you can simply do:

```
if (+d[key]===+d[key]) {
  d[key] = +d[key]
}
```

Here is another demo, with negatives, floats and scientific notation:

```js
var data = d3.csvParse(d3.select("#csv").text());

data.forEach(function(d) {
  for (var key in d) {
    if (+d[key]===+d[key]) {
      d[key] = +d[key]
    }
  }
});

console.log(data);
```

```css
pre {
  display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<pre id="csv">header1,header2,header3
foo,foo2,12.12
bar,bar2,-2345
baz,baz2,2.4e6</pre>
```

Answer (score -2):

I'd use `parseFloat` (or `parseInt` if you know you don't have to care about floats)

```
function maybeNumber(someString) {
    var result = parseFloat(someString, 10);
    if (isNaN(result)) {
        return someString;
    }
    return result;
}

data = data.map(maybeNumber);
```

It's safer than letting type coercion loose on your data.

Comment: @Hack-R This solution doesn't work. If you try "543rrdrd", it will simply drop the letters and return "543".

Comment: @Hack-R and `/^\d+$/` isn't capturing negative numbers, scientific notation or floats.  You're already guessing, but I'd argue that trying to run it through a real parser is the more correct way to guess.  Also, coercion is going to convert valid US ZIP codes to octal.

Comment: @dtanders I'll have to come back to this tomorrow. I think I can always bulk up the regex, but if there's a way to get it working with the parse functions that will be great. I'll do some more testing on this tomorrow.